# Session Sharing Between 2 Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, session-state

I am doing session sharing between two website on same server using sqlserver session mode but it is worked on virtual directory not worked on server while uploaded the site on the server.

Both website using same database and same server.Can anybody tell me that what is i missed.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the connection settings for session state to your live machines web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
  sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
    source=SampleSqlServer;" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom session state implementation that will allow to share session between 2 different sites.

Default SQL session state indexes record with {session key (i.e. from cookies) + application ID} - as result even the same session ID on the same server will get separate information for different sites. There is no supported way to configure it to ignore application ID part.

Comment: How can i do custom session state implementation?

Comment: @user1939371 try searching - http://www.bing.com/search?q=custom+session+state+implementation